# Store specific array in cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a session which stores 2 arrays, $_SESSION["info"] and $_SESSION["cart"] now when the user logs out the info session is destroyed so unset($_SESSION["info"] however the cart session remains. The info session stores the user's id, now I am trying to retrieve the ID of that user from the info array and store it in a cookie when the user logs out, so when the user logs back in, if the userID stored in the session matches the cookie userID it uses the cart array relevant to that userID.

This is what I have so far, in my logout.php:

```
$_COOKIE["userID"] = $_SESSION["info"]["id"];
unset($_SESSION["info"]);
```

In my wishlist.phtml:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
    if (count($_SESSION["cart"])>0) {
       echo '<br><br>';
       echo '<table class="table table-hover"><thead><tr>';
       echo '<th>Owner</th><th>Car</th><th>Price</th><th class="text-center">Action</th>   </tr>';
       echo '</thead><tbody>';
       foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $wish) {

        echo '<tr><td>' . $wish["username"]. '</td><td>' . $wish["car"]. '</td><td>' .$wish["price"]. '</td><td class="text-center"><a href="/removecar.php?car='.$key. '"><button id="view" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">x</button></a></td></tr>';

    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">You do not have any cars in your wishlist.</div>';
     };

  }

?>
```

Does anyone know how I should do this?

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE is read only array, you need to use [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) like

```
setcookie('userID', $_SESSION["info"]["id"], time()+60*60*24*30, '/');
```

BTW, you will not be able to associate user id back to session, so it is better to save whole cart in database or cookie